# how to set weight of textview Dyanamicaly inside Tablerow in TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I have three textview inside table row but positioning of the that textview is not properly align and i am dyanamicaly adding  textview inside tablerow in tablelayout,how do i set weight to textview?
Plzz Help me

```
 TableLayout table= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
        TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
        TextView txt1=new TextView(this);
        txt1.setTextSize(20);
        TextView txt2=new TextView(this);
        txt2.setTextSize(20);
        TextView txt3=new TextView(this);
        txt3.setTextSize(20);
        txt1.setText("Name");
        txt2.setText("Quantity");
        txt3.setText("Unit");
        tableRow.addView(txt1);
        tableRow.addView(txt2);
        tableRow.addView(txt3);
        table.addView(tableRow);
```

Comment: paste your code

Comment: listen dipali ji, what did you tried?

Comment: i update question with basic code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set `weightSum` below way.

```
    TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowparam = new TableRow.LayoutParams();  tableRowparam.weight=0.50f; 
txt1.setLayoutParams(tableRowparam);
```

In the Upper Code I take `0.50f` means there are `2` `TextView` in the `TableRow`. you can change by your requirement.

Comment: @AkshayPadalkar Post your error logcat in question.

Comment: TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowparam = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tableRowparam.weight=0.50f;
        txt1.setLayoutParams(tableRowparam);

Comment: TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowparam = new TableRow.LayoutParams(); tableRowparam.weight=0.50f; txt1.setLayoutParams(tableRowparam);


this code is work for me

Comment: @AkshayPadalkar If that work for you then Accept the Answer so it will help other.

Comment: can you tell me if i have 2 text view then my weight will be ?
i set 0.50f and 1.0f but it will not occupy entire row

Answer (score 0):

If you have to set the weight onto the children that are supposed to scale.

1 means 100% scaling by default, if you want 3 textvies to spread evenly set 0.33 as weight for each.

get idea from below code for your all textview:

use `TableLayout.LayoutParams`

```
TableRow.LayoutParams trlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.33f);

tvFirst.setLayoutParams(trlp);  //tvFirst is first textview 

tr.add(tvFirst);
```

Thanks

Comment: @AkshayPadalkar, please check updated answer and import proper layout params

Comment: TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowparam = new TableRow.LayoutParams(); tableRowparam.weight=0.50f; txt1.setLayoutParams(tableRowparam);

Comment: can you tell me if i have 2 text view then my weight will be ?
i set 0.50f and 1.0f but it will not occupy entire row